# How to generate DHCP Decline scenario / packets

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I have a dhcp packets sniffer, which needs to log if it sees **dhcp decline** response coming from client.I need to know the scenario where client can send dhcp decline response to dhcp server.
I tried to get this reproduce by minimizing small range of ip's at dhcpserver and allocating duplicate static ip's to a client says client_A and running dhclient on client_B.But client_B accepts duplicate ip (ip which is already with ip client_A), instead of sending dhcpdecline response.

Is this a better and guaranteed way to reproduce dhcp decline scenario.
Clients I m using are ubuntu and for dhcp server various options are available like vyos/microsoft.

Thanks and advance !!

Comment: Most DHCP servers already log decline responses.

Comment: I have a separate sniffer app, which is looking for dhcp requests.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it should be possible, but it's going to require a bit of fiddling...

As you suggested in the comments, dhclient doesn't validate DHCP server responses for router addresses so I went to the documents and found out what kind of situation might cause dhclient to send a DHCPDECLINE.

**Dhclient** docs show that **dhclient-script** is called when a lease is issued:

> ...network configuration script invoked by dhclient when it gets a
>   lease.    If unspecified, the default CLIENTBINDIR/dhclient-script is
>   used.   See dhclient-script(8)for a description of this file.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/dhclient.8.html

**Dhclient-script** docs show that before configuring the address offered by the DHCP server, dhclient-script ARPs for it and raises a DHCPDECLINE if the address already exists.

> Before actually configuring the address, dhclient-script should
>   somehow ARP for it and exit with a nonzero status if it receives a
>   reply. In this case, the client will send a DHCPDECLINE message to the
>   server and acquire a different address.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/dhclient-script.8.html

I haven't got a copy of Ubuntu to look at at the mo (check your /etc/dhclient-script), but the source code for the Linux **dhclient-script** can be found here http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/isc-dhcp/wily/view/head:/client/scripts/linux

I'm thinking (but unfortunately can't test it) that you could backup your existing dhclient-script and edit this section

```
 Must be used on exit.   Invokes the local dhcp client exit hooks, if any.
exit_with_hooks() {
  exit_status=$1
  if [ -f /etc/dhclient-exit-hooks ]; then
    . /etc/dhclient-exit-hooks
  fi
# probably should do something with exit status of the local script
  exit $exit_status
}
```

I think changing `exit $exit_status` to `exit 1` would cause any DHCP lease to be declined...

Give it a try. If it works as I think it should, it will totally break the DHCP client but should generate a DHCPDECLINE each time you run **dhclient**.

Comment: Tried editing dhclient-script, but no success yet !I was just thinking if there can be a be a way wihout editing source code of any client/server.

Comment: Sorry - my bad. Try a non-zero exit status. (i.e. 1). i'm not sure what will trigger a DHCPDECLINE, and unfortunately don't have a Linux system in front of me to test.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see a way of changing this without editing the source code. Check the docs - the only way the default DHCP client will refuse to accept a DHCP offer is when an ARP check shows the IP address has already been issued...

Comment: Changing script to 1 does not help, tried that as well.Kindly let me know if you get the chance to test this on your system.

Answer (score 0):

From any traffic-generator create an ethernet IPv4-DHCP message type53 with 04 for Decline and 06 bytes for NAK

Comment: that wa snot the question, the opener asked for, WHAT is the reason not howto generate such messages - please improve your answer